# How to chain multiple command line responses in Python?

Tags: python, shell, command-line

I've been trying to run a script within another python script with no luck.

The script I am trying to run is garminbackup.py which can be found in the following repo.

https://github.com/petergardfjall/garminexport

When you run this script from the command line it asks you for some information, username, location to save files, ect...

```
command = 'python garminbackup.py --backup-dir=Name email --format tcx'
```

It then asks for a password, and once entered it starts to download the garmin files to the directory provided. My goal is to create a program which loops through multiple accounts and updates the data in each folder.

My issue is that I cannot seem to get the subprocess module in python to performance this.

I've tried the following command with no luck. It seems to get stuck on the enter password input screen and does not do anything else.

```
import subprocess,shlex
from subprocess import PIPE,call
import os

p = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
p.stdin.write("password\n")
p.wait()
```

I've searched for hours with little luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should first read the stout in order to get to the password prompt and then send it. Also I would advise you to take a look at `expect/pexpect` library, I find it very helpful for dealing with "waiting for prompts" and "sending inputs".

Comment: While not a solution, you might want to take more control over the prompts for input by requesting them upfront from the user and then simply supply them as command line parameters e.g. --password xyz.

Comment: I'd advise to not call that python script as a generic executable in a new (sub)process. Rather load the python module(s)/package and call rely on its functions and classes. Check what `garminbackup.py` does and you can derive your own actions from that.

Comment: I second the comment of @OndrejK. but if you still want to do it your own way, you can just add the password as a command line argument `--password`.

Comment: please, never pass password in command line. this is such a horrible idea. if i ever have the privilege to just take a look at the running processes of the same computer, your passwords are immediately disclosed, not to mention there might be chances of leave a plain text log in filesystem due to some monitoring mechanism. there is no production ready application will ask for password through a command line.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr He is touched an important point([maybe you want try this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login)).

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I added the --password to the command line and it worked. I ventured in to the pexpect territory without much luck.

Comment: with everything I've said you decided to do the wrong thing? which part pexpect does not help you? you should post another question on how to set this up properly. all those comments asking you to pass in password from command line should be deleted.

Comment: hey HuStmpHrr, I appreciate for your advice. The data is not that sensitive so I am not worried about the password being hacked or stolen. This particular solution works for my needs, although I see the point you are making, I'd take this in to consideration in any other situaiton.

Answer (score 1):

Although the OP solved it by using the `--password` option, others might stumble upon the same problem and as already [pointed out by HuStmpHrr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49014843/how-to-chain-multiple-command-line-responses-in-python#comment85038023_49014843) it is not a good idea to pass a password in the command line.

## Why it did not work

The called script, in this case `garminbackup.py` uses [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/getpass.html). As hinted in the documentation the implementaion of getpass is more complecated than just reading the stdin:

> [...] On Unix, the prompt is written to the file-like object stream.
>   stream defaults to the controlling terminal (/dev/tty) or if that is
>   unavailable to sys.stderr (this argument is ignored on Windows).
>
> If echo free input is unavailable getpass() falls back to printing a
>   warning message to stream and reading from sys.stdin and issuing a
>   GetPassWarning.

## How it should work

We could emulate a dummy terminal, but that is to complicated without a library (see next chapter).

Another way is to get rid of the information that there is a terminal ("If echo free input is unavailable"). This turned out harder than I expected, normally running a command as `cat | command | cat` should get rid of the tty detection, but it seems getpass is either to clever or to ignorant to change its behaviour.

## The better way: pexpect

As already [mentioned by LohmarASHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49014843/how-to-chain-multiple-command-line-responses-in-python#comment85035570_49014843), if you can use [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html) (`pip install pexpect`) you should. It is made for exactly this and will cover all the corner cases.

> For example:
>
> ```
> child = pexpect.spawn('scp foo user@example.com:.')
> child.expect('Password:')
> child.sendline(mypassword)
> ```
>
> This works even for commands that ask for passwords or other input
>   **outside of the normal stdio streams**. For example, ssh reads input
>   directly from the TTY device which bypasses stdin.

To stick with the OP's example, but using pexpect:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pexpect

command = 'python garminbackup.py --backup-dir=Name email --format tcx'

p = pexpect.spawn(command)  # instead of subprocess.Popen
p.expect(":")               # This is waiting for the prompt "Enter password:", but I rather only use ":" to cope with internationalisation issues
p.sendline("password")
print p.read()              # Output the sub-processes output 
p.wait()
```